# How to import fontsaweome using npm in tailwind files

Tags: npm, font-awesome, tailwind-css

how do i  import or include fontawesome files from the src/styles.css to public/styles.css, please i need help on how to write that perfectly
i don't know how to reference  the fontawesome files in-order to show the con e.g i all.css and webfonts
i actually want to run it locally with npm

see my code

@import "background-image: url(//node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css)";

this does not work but i tried this

@import "background-image: url(.../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css)";
the path does not direct me to node_modules folder

[check code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5ZWp.png)